# One Web Service Having two methods.. exposing those methods to different WSDL..?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have spring based web Service having two methods in it `getName()` and `getPlace()`.
I want to expose them in two different wsdls could it be achieved ..?

Comment: Nope you cannot do that as long as the two methods are in a same class.

Comment: Okay.. so can we link two web services ?? suppose i want to call getName() from getPLace() as they both are on different web service..?

Comment: When you say _ different web service_ does it mean they are on different servers ?

Comment: No..Different wsdls..I meant.

Comment: are they deployed in same server ?

Comment: yes they are on the same server.

Comment: Well, in that case you can always call `getName()` from `getPLace()` in your java code.